# dynamic_cast macro rescue NULL

Tags: c++, macros, dynamic-cast

I want to use a `dynamic_cast` intrinsic in my generated C++ code. The macro definition looks like:

```
#define jcast(T, v) (dynamic_cast<T*>(v))
```

Unfortunately, because the code is generated, this situation can occur:

```
foo(jcast(UWiseObject, NULL));
```

A compiler said that:

```
error: `nullptr_t` is not a pointer.
```

How can I rescue `NULL` in this situation? I really want something like:

```
if (v) 
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(v);
else
    return NULL;
```

Comment: Why can't you change the macro definition, if that's what you want to do?

Comment: Why not do it as a function. That's preferable to a macro I think.

Comment: why are you using a **macro**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's macro's for you. Write real C++ instead:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
T* jcast(U* u) { return dynamic_cast<T*>(u); }
template<typename T>
T* jcast(nullptr_t) { return nullptr; }
```

Comment: Why `U` before `T`?

Comment: Error somewhere between brain and keyboard, it of course should have been in the alphabetical order. `U` is a deduced type, `T` isn't.